# Why won't Node `https.get` request work on `heroku local` but work when deployed?

Tags: node.js, git, bash, heroku, https

I have a Node.js app that I wrote and successfully deployed to a Heroku app via Bash. From my computer running Ubuntu at home it runs fine locally too.

However, I have just cloned the repository to a Windows machine and while I've successfully managed to push updates to the Heroku remote, which work, whenever I run `heroku local` from Windows and try to access the local version (localhost:5000), that page serves an error and my command line returns `TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters` and `layer.js:95.5`.

The app uses `https.get` and this seems to be the problem line, locally.

I'm reluctant to try adapting my code since it works fine on Heroku itself and works fine on my Ubuntu machine -- so can only assume that something needs configuring on my Windows machine.

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: In your code, are you getting an absolute path to a folder or something like that? Windows's path uses '\' and not '/', it might be the issue or there is a space in path somewhere. What code is at `layer.js:95.5`?

Comment: @ShanShan Thanks for responding. The line/`layer.js` looks like it is part of the Express package. The `https.get` that I think is repsonsible is within some Express routing. I have just run the code through straight Node (rather than `heroku local`) and got the same error. The point about the Windows path is interesting but it wouldn't affect an API call would it?

Comment: Hum: https://github.com/strongloop/express/issues/2511 Do your routes contains any special character? Or maybe a folder has a strange name? T don't think so since it works on ubuntu but I'm still asking. I think it'll be quite difficult to pinpoint the source of the issue.

Comment: Thank you. The problem turned out to be something else but I really appreciate your efforts. I've posted an answer below. If you're interested in this and anything in my answer does not make sense, please let me know and I'll update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

Be careful which variable keys you choose for config/`.env` in Heroku. Windows has some reserved keys (like `user` and `path`) which will mean trying to set your own values against these keys will not work.

---

### The detail

It turns out the issue is with my choice of variable names as used in my `.env` file.

When you have data that you don't want to commit to a repository (in my case, an authentication key and details for my account) you can add them to Heroku as "config vars" -- `key=value` pairs which Heroku keeps separate to your code so you can version and share your repository as needed and others can add their own details.

When running Heroku locally however using the `heroku local` command from the toolbelt, these variables need to come from somewhere else. Heroku's help recommends setting them up as `key=value` pairs in a file called `.env` (which you can then add to `.gitignore` to prevent accidental committing.

Unfortunately, in my case it was my choice of variable keys in `.env` that caused the problem. I had created dependencies on variables called `user` and `path` but these seem to be reserved on Windows and have a special purpose and therefore could not be overwritten by what was in my `.env` file. This is why what worked for me on my Ubuntu machine would not work directly on Windows.

You can see this in action by calling console.log(`process.env.user`, `process.env.path`) from Node on a Windows machine.

Now that I have changed the variable names to something non-reserved `heroku local` works fine. Calling the programme via `node` command will still not work as it is not set up to pick up the variables from `.env` as Heroku.

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Good to know :) The windows PATH variable is full of `\ ` and `;` so no wonder Express refused to load it. However, I tried on Win10 and `user` doesn't seem to be a reserved name.

Comment: Could be setup I have here on a work machine. The `user` value I saw was the username for logging into accounts across the organisation. It may not be an issue for everyone, but for my purposes I had to avoid it.